# cannot access carousel by its id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, carousel

I have a carousel running at my site

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="weekCarouselTemplate">
        <br>
<br>
    <br>
        <br>
            <div id="weekCarousel_{{$index}}" class="carousel slide">
                <a href="#weekCarousel_{{$index}}" data-slide="prev" class="prevweek">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div  class="item" ng-repeat="week in ls_weeks" data-slide-number="{{$index}}" ng-class="makeActive(week)">


                        <div class="weekList">
                            <div style="float:left"; ng-class="highlightDay($index,week,usrLifestyle.lsid)" ng-repeat="d in ls_days track by $index" ng-click='weekdayClicked($index,week,usrLifestyle.lsName,usrLifestyle.lsid,usrLifestyle.insertTimestmp)'>
                            {{d}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <a href="#weekCarousel_{{$index}}" data-slide="next" class="nextweek">
                    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <br>
                <br>
    </script>
```

which i tried to access the by using the id which is not working

```
angular.element("#weekCarouselTemplate").bind('slid', function (e) {
  console.log("slid event after!");
});
```

Comment: What error did it show? Did you check the console?

Comment: isnt that just the `id` of the template? `weekCarousel_{{$index}}` would be the slider `id` would'nt it?

Comment: it doesn't show any error

Comment: is `bind('slid', function` just a typo here or is it in your code? i.e. should be `bind('slide', function`

Comment: @atmd its typo it is slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `angular.element` function does not work this way. You need to pass either a DOM element or html string (not a selector string) to it.

```
var carouselElem = document.getElementById('weekCarouselTemplate');
var $carouselElem = angular.element(carouselElem);
$carouselElem.bind('slide', function(e){
    //something  
});
```

More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).